# $('input').tagsinput('removeAll'); creates new search box

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have my search box here:

```
<input id="search_bar" type="text" value="" data-role="tagsinput" class="form-
control" placeholder="Enter Tags"/>
```

I have a button that functions to removes all my tags from my search box:

```
<button type="button" align="center" class="btn btn-warning" value="Back" 
id="go_back">Back</button>
```

The javascript function is as follows:

```
$("#go_back").click(function(){
    $('input').tagsinput('removeAll');
});
```

This button is supposed to remove all the tags on the search bar, it does that except it creates another search box inside the search box. How do I make it so that it doesn't create a new search box every time I reset the tags?

Before clearing tags:
[image: before clearing tags]

After clearing tags:
[image: after clearing tags]

Comment: Can you provide a working example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there anything else to the way you've applied this?
OR, are there any other inputs on the page..? Something is odd.

So I searched to find out what code you're on about and think I found it http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ and did the following....

1. Applied the click event code you wrote to the paragraph above the first example on the page
2. Added an id to the input field in the first example called "arse", I don't know why I choose silly id names like that
3. I then clicked the paragraph above and the tags disappeared and I was able to type in them again

So maybe do that, using the id to your input field instead.

```
    $("#go_back").on('click', function(){
        $('#search_bar').tagsinput('removeAll');
    });
```

Comment: my input field already has an id called "search_bar"

i tried using that instead of input in my js and it didn't work, it didnt remove tags, but at least i didnt create a new search bar

Comment: i didnt see the # before search_bar, apparently adding that fixed it.